# Requiring Protocol and Class in Swift Properties

Tags: swift, ios8

In Objective-C you can require a class and additional protocol implementations for properties:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIViewController<UISplitViewDelegate> *viewController;
```

Is this possible in Swift? From the documentation it looks like you can only require either a class or a protocol.

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474061/whats-the-swift-equivalent-of-declaring-typedef-someclasssomeprotocol-mytype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 4 you can do this by:

```
let viewController: UIViewController & UISplitViewDelegate
```

Answer (score 16):

There are actually two of ways to achieve this in Swift:

1. **Using an empty "phantom" protocol**. Create an empty protocol and make `UIViewController` conform to it. This is the most "Swift" method, it's safe and it's dynamic (doesn't require specifying a class at compile-time).

   ```
   protocol _UIViewControllerType {}
   extension UIViewController: _UIViewControllerType {}

   class MyClass {
       weak var viewController: protocol<UISplitViewControllerDelegate, _UIViewControllerType>?
   }
   ```

   You can also declare a `typealias` for this type (just to reduce the code mess).

   ```
   class MyClass {
       typealias ViewControllerType = protocol<UISplitViewControllerDelegate, _UIViewControllerType>
       weak var viewController: ViewControllerType?
   }
   ```
2. **Using generic constraints**. As mentioned by [fnc12](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27806730/736649) and [Konstantin Koval](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27806730/736649). This is safe, but doesn't allow you to "swap" the view controller instance at run-time.

   ```
   class MyClass<T: UIViewController where T: UISplitViewControllerDelegate> {
       weak var viewController: T?
   }
   ```

---

I hope the next Swift release adds a way to specify both constraints without using a "phantom protocol"...

```
typealias ViewControllerType = UIViewController: UISplitViewControllerDelegate // wish
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but solution 1 doesn't allow me to use any UIViewController methods without casting, right? E.g. `viewController.title = "Some Title"`. Or use it as a method parameter where a UIViewController is required? E.g. `otherViewController.addChildViewController( viewController)`.

Comment: Yes. You would have to add an extra `let viewController = object as UIViewController` line every time you want to use its API.

Comment: I still think this is a small cost.

Comment: Well, for me not having to cast is the whole point. Otherwise I could just declare the property as AnyObject.

Comment: Then you could get a runtime fatal error, as this could be an instace of `CMMotionActivityManager`. Using a protocol at least ensures that it's not *literally* any object.

Comment: If you want to avoid the cast entirely, the second option might be more suitable. There is no `XYZClass<XYZProtocol>` syntax equivalent in Swift (as of today).

Comment: Wow, this feels so wrong... Thank you so much for this workaround. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do that

```
class A < T : SomeClass where T: Comparable> {
    var myProperty: T
    init(t :T) {
        myProperty = t
    }
}
```

Declare class `A` that has a property of type T. T is `SomeClass` or subclass and it has to adopt `Comparable` protocol

When declaring a property you can use protocol as type

```
class MyClass {
    var nsobject: NSObjectProtocol
    init(object : NSObjectProtocol) {
        nsobject = object
    }
}

// Pure Swift
protocol RandomNumberGenerator {
}

class Dice {
    let generator: RandomNumberGenerator
    //specify many protocols
    let printer: protocol<Printable, NicePrintable> 
}
```

You can read [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_351)

Comment: So how would I specify a property that is required to be a UIViewController and implements the UISplitViewDelegate protocol?

Answer (score 4):

> Same as @akashivskyy answer, using **empty "phantom" protocol**
>   But here i am doing it as separate class which implements that
>   protocol - MyViewController, which can be used as type for var
>   declaration. Which simplified in my implementaion.

```
@objc protocol MySplitViewControllerDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    func controllerTitle() -> String
    optional func mySplitView() // write delegates
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, MySplitViewControllerDelegate {
    func controllerTitle() -> String {
        return ""
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private(set) weak var viewController: MyViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is where generics are needed.

```
@property (nonatomic) UIViewController<UISplitViewDelegate> *viewController;
```

Assume you want class called 'MyClass" to have a property called 'viewController' with type UIViewController (or subclass) and that conforms UISplitViewDelegate protocol. In Swift your code will look like

```
class MyClass<T:UIViewController where T:UISplitViewControllerDelegate>:NSObject{
    var viewController:T?

    override init(){
        super.init()
        //..
    }

    //  etc..
}
```

Notice

```
class MyClass<T:UIViewController where T:UISplitViewControllerDelegate>:NSObject
```

line. Here you specify a random T type but you also specify you want T to be derived from UIViewController and conform UISplitViewControllerDelegate. This condition will be checked during compilation. And you declare a property in this line

```
var viewController:T?
```

and specify its type as T.
And one question left - how to declare variable of type MyClass? I provide a minimum code from a sample project to illustrate more clearly.

```
class MyClass<T:UIViewController where T:UISplitViewControllerDelegate>:NSObject{
    var viewController:T?

    override init(){
        super.init()
        //..
    }

    //  etc..
}

class ViewController: UIViewController,UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        var a=MyClass <ViewController> ()
        a.viewController=self
        //..
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //..
}
```

More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html)

Good luck with generics.