# Declare variable with generic type in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics, types

I have a line of code from Obj-C:

```
GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *filter;
```

How can I convert it to Swift? I try some solutions but it doesn't work :(

```
var filter = GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput>
var filter:GPUImageOutput = GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput>
```

Comment: also: [What's the Swift equivalent of declaring `typedef SomeClass<SomeProtocol> MyType`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474061)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a generic in Objective-C. Obj-C does not support generics.

That notation is used to indicate protocol conformance. So it is declared as a `GPUImageOutput` that implemente the `GPUImageInput` protocol.

I believe it can be translated to this in Swift:

```
var filter: GPUImageInput
// or
var filter: GPUImageOutput
```